# Forward Propagation with Dropout

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working through Andrew Ng new deep learning Coursera course.

We are implementing the following code :

```
def forward_propagation_with_dropout(X, parameters, keep_prob = 0.5):

 np.random.seed(1)
    
    # retrieve parameters
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    b1 = parameters["b1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    b2 = parameters["b2"]
    W3 = parameters["W3"]
    b3 = parameters["b3"]
    
    # LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = relu(Z1)
    
    ### START CODE HERE ### (approx. 4 lines)         # Steps 1-4 below correspond to the Steps 1-4 described above. 
    D1 = np.random.rand(*A1.shape)                                # Step 1: initialize matrix D1 = np.random.rand(..., ...)
    D1 = (D1 < 0.5)                                        # Step 2: convert entries of D1 to 0 or 1 (using keep_prob as the threshold)
        
    A1 = A1*D1                                        # Step 3: shut down some neurons of A1
    A1 = A1 / keep_prob                                         # Step 4: scale the value of neurons that haven't been shut down
        
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = relu(Z2)
        
    ### START CODE HERE ### (approx. 4 lines)
    D2 =np.random.rand(*A2.shape)                                        # Step 1: initialize matrix D2 = np.random.rand(..., ...)
    D2 = (D2 < 0.5)                                        # Step 2: convert entries of D2 to 0 or 1 (using keep_prob as the threshold)
    A2 = A2 * D2                                         # Step 3: shut down some neurons of A2
    A2 = A2 / keep_prob                                         # Step 4: scale the value of neurons that haven't been shut down
        
### END CODE HERE ###
     Z3 = np.dot(W3, A2) + b3
     A3 = sigmoid(Z3)
      
     cache = (Z1, D1, A1, W1, b1, Z2, D2, A2, W2, b2, Z3, A3, W3, b3)
        
     return A3, cache
```

Calling:

```
X_assess, parameters = forward_propagation_with_dropout_test_case()

A3, cache = forward_propagation_with_dropout(X_assess, parameters, keep_prob = 0.7)
print ("A3 = " + str(A3))
```

My output was :

```
A3 = [[ 0.36974721  0.49683389  0.04565099  0.49683389  0.36974721]]
```

The expected output should be :

```
A3 = [[ 0.36974721 0.00305176 0.04565099 0.49683389 0.36974721]]
```

Only one number difference. Any ideas why ?

I think it is because of the way I shaped D1 and D2.

Comment: I have the same code and did get the correct results. Have you try re-running all the previous cells in the notebook and checking everything is in place?

Comment: @IUF I missed closing a parentheses. Yes the code is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because you put D1 = (D1 < 0.5) and D2 = (D2 < 0.5)
You need to put "keep_prob" instead of 0.5